# user OpenOffice java api，after conversion the word and pdf are not the same format

Tags: java, pdf

The code

```
DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration configuration = new DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration();
            try {
                configuration.setOfficeHome("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenOffice 4");
                configuration.setPortNumbers(8100); // 设置转换端口，默认为8100
                configuration.setTaskExecutionTimeout(1000 * 60 * 20L);// 设置任务执行超时为5分钟
                configuration.setTaskQueueTimeout(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24L);// 设置任务队列超时为24小时

                OfficeManagerSingle single = OfficeManagerSingle.getInstance();
                OfficeManager officeManager = single.getOfficeManager(configuration);
                officeManager.start();
                OfficeDocumentConverter converter = new OfficeDocumentConverter(
                        officeManager);

                converter.convert(docFile, pdfFile);
                if(docFile.exists()) {
                    FileUtils.forceDelete(docFile);
                    logger.info("源文件临时文件已删除!");
                }
                logger.info("PDF转换成功，PDF输出：" + pdfFile.getPath());
                officeManager.stop();
                }
```

[image: the word document]
***the pdf document has the image,but I do not want the image.***
[image: the pdf document]

*How can I make the pdf format as the same as the word?*

Comment: Do you know where the images came from? Aren't they yours?

Comment: no,the word document downloads from other place,I just convert it to pdf,then pdf to image.But I open the word,there are not the images.